# How to create dynamic subdomain rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-routing

How can i create subdomain for each user that registers on my site? For example userone.mysite.com and usertwo.mysite.com.

In php it can be done using apache virtual host, but i can't figure out how to do the same in Ruby on Rails. Here is how it can be done in apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com *.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

I went through many blogs but couldn't find the solution.
Please Advice.

Comment: Do you need physical sub domain or just virtual domain

Comment: I need virtual domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName mysite.com
      ServerAlias *.my_site.com
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my_site
      <Directory /var/www/html/my_site>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
         # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
         Require all granted
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

and do not forgot change cname * entry to your domain in DNS

Comment: Please let me know the hostintg provider so that I can provide you the exact cname configuration

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Dinesh Saini answer - you also need to update Rails configs accordingly. For example, if you need deep subdomains you should change 
config.action_dispatch.tld_length in staging.rb and you should re-check routes.rb.

Live example: I had to implement shop displaying by subdomain - example URL
my-shop.shop.testapp.com.So what I did except server config changes

```
   constraints (lambda { |req| req.subdomains[1] == 'shop' }) do
      get '/', to: 'shopes#show', as: :shop
   end
```

In controller to find resource

```
   Shop.find_by(id: request.subdomains[0])
```

I also set

```
   config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 2
```

I did this for staging env because it has such URL staging.testapp.com so I need another subdomain level. I think for you it's only good to check that it's has 1.